# ¿Como cerrar sesion despues de inactividad en Vue JS (JWT)?

Tags: vue.js, axios, jwt, vuex

tengo inicio de session por tokens, cabe señalar que en mi REST API ya tengo los siguientes endpoints:

> auth/signin
>
> auth/refresh

los cuales me devuelven un token valido con su exp date, actualmente tengo mi aplicacion en Vue, la cual por medio de axios interceptor cierro la sesion si el token  no es valido, o lo renuevo segun sea el caso
pero **estoy buscando que la sesion se cierre despues de un tiempo X de inactividad** , podrian orientarme si hay alguna libreria con la cual pueda lograr eso?

Comment: El problema que veo en tu aplicación, es que al estar usando JWT no tienes un control directo sobre cuándo dejan de ser válidos pues la validez se encuentra en ellos mismos. En [esta respuesta en el homónimo en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462856/how-to-expire-a-jwt-token-manually) puedes encontrar una posible solución al problema, que básicamente es tener una blacklist de los tokens que han sido marcados como inválidos. Entonces lo primero que harías es verificar si el token no se encuentra en la blacklist, posteriormente puedes continuar con el proceso normal de validación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esta librería te podría funcionar perfectamente
[idle-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idle-vue)